# Can I set php.ini for individual folders in Linux (Debian)?

Tags: php, linux, apache, server

I'm new to PHP and server configuration in general, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.
Basically I have LAMP on my laptop (I installed Debian, Apache, MySQL, PHP separately, not as a bundle). The websites on my localhost are located in var/www/html/. I made a subfolder called 'php' (var/www/html/php/) where I'm learning and experimenting with PHP code.

Now, I made a php.ini file in var/www/html/php/ which only contains 2 lines:

```
display_errors = on
display_startup_errors = on
```

All I want is for the errors to display so that I know what I'm doing wrong.
Anyway, that didn't work. So I moved the php.ini file to var/www/html/ but it still didn't work. In the end I had to go to the folder where PHP is installed and edit the php.ini file there (i.e. /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini).

I can see the errors now, but what if I don't want to turn on display_errors for every site in my localhost? What if I want to have display_errors=On for some folders and display_errors=off for some folders? How do I do that?

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php and https://support.tigertech.net/php-value In short you can modify php settings in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.htaccess` `php_value` mechanism to modify php values.

For instance, having

```
php_value display_errors on
```

On your `.htaccess` will set this value for every file in that folders and every descending folders.

More informations here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php